# substring matching in lucene with a list of items

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

lets say I have a field in my database: 'city'.
I have a list of cities that I would like to get results where the 'city' field is one of the cities in my list.

2 problems:

1. my list is long (around 3000 cities). is there a better way than:

   `city:"city1" OR city:"city2" OR ... OR city:"city3000"`
2. sometimes the city is listed as part of a bigger string. so I want results where `'city:"city1"'`
   but also `'city:"my city is city1"'` and `'city:"my city is city1 and its nice"'` or `'city:"city1 is my city"'`

I would imagine that using `'city:"*city1*"'` would so but lucene does not support `*` in the beginning of the search term.

Comment: Does it have to be in the Lucene expression language?

Comment: well yea. it is